# Facebook doesn't reload canvas after authorization

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have the following JavaScript on a canvas app, which gets called if the user is NOT logged in (checked via php).

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '(appid)',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
  }
  else {
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange',function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
        setTimeout('window.location.reload()',0);
        };
        });
  FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_friends'});
  }
});
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js\";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

The problem is that the Window doesn't reload even though I tell it to do so. I know the function is called after pressing "login" and accepting permissions, because if I include and alert it shows at that point.

As you can see I already tried wrapping it in a setTimeout, but that doesn't work.

If I press F5 after this, the page reloads and I'm logged in.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, all I had to do was change to:

```
top.location.href="https://apps.facebook.com/appname";
```

instead of `window.location.reload()`

This also prevents the browser from asking if it should resubmit the data.